# How can you add or remove workers from delayed_jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

On a similar note, how can you know how many workers there are currently assigned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on your local machine, just run one of the following

```
# starts the worker
rake jobs:work 
# kills it
Control + C on your keyboard
```

or

```
# starts the worker
script/delayed_job start
# kills it
script/delayed_job stop
```

Additionally, here are some commands to spawn multiple workers: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Delayed-job-command-details

If you want a list of currently running workers, you would do

```
script/delayed_job status
```

and this would return each process (which you'd then have to count to get the integer value)

If you are on Heroku, you can do `heroku workers` to get the number of current workers, and `heroku workers 2` to start two workers or `heroku workers 0` to kill all workers.

You can also use HireFireApp.com to manage all of your workers for you on Heroku.

Since you didn't specify what type of environment you are running DJ on, please let me know if these don't answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

`$ ps ax |grep delayed_job` can show you any details directly

Answer (score 1):

The "ps" suggestion works better after first looking int RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids for delayed_job*.pid files.

Together this tells you what DJ thinks it's running and what is actually running. If one of those files contains a process ID that you can't find in the ps output, that's an indicator that DJ has a worker that has died that it hasn't realized.